# Adding a progress bar(NSProgressIndicator) during level generation in SKScene

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, progress-bar, sprite-kit

I'm creating a game using the sprite-kit framework. I didn't programe so much for OS X or iOS and i think transition between SKScene and views or screens have many differences.
I created a game menu using Sprite-kit and want to put a progress bar showing progress of level generation and other game operations and after that move to another SKScene with the scenario, hero, enemies, etc.

I found that Cocoa has a progress bar class and UI object. I pick an sample from [cocoaControls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/lbprogressbar)

I know how to create transitions between SkScenes, there is no problem about that, but looking into the cocoa controls sample code i found a xib file which i don't know how to put into two skscenes and how to load it from the Skscene's game menu.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "level generation"?

Comment: Level generation is the process of load parameter, load textures, generate map, apply the textures, place the enemies, etc like in all games.